# Postgres ignoring GIN index for LIKE query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am working in Postgres 9.4. I have a table and index like this:

```
                                              Table "public.title"
             Column              |          Type           |                     Modifiers                      
---------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                              | integer                 | not null default nextval('title_id_seq'::regclass)
 pty_addr                        | character varying(1000) | not null
```

I have a GIN index on the `pty_addr` column:

```
"title_pty_add_15f367_gin" gin (pty_addr)
```

My query is this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "title" WHERE  pty_addr LIKE '%FOO%';
```

This query is performing a sequential scan, taking 1.2 seconds:

```
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on title  (cost=0.00..193271.60 rows=599 width=4446) (actual time=1.191..1220.640 rows=7945 loops=1)
   Filter: ((pty_addr)::text ~~ '%FOO%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 3592055
 Planning time: 0.330 ms
 Execution time: 1220.992 ms
```

Why isn't this query using the index?

Comment: For what it's worth: the searches I need to perform will be case-insensitive.

Comment: You can't natively build a gin index on varchar(1000).  Are you using some extension to allow you to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to index for LIKE which are not prefix queries, or for ILIKE queries, then you should look into the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) extension, giving an index that would look like:

```
"title_pty_add_15f367_gin" gin (pty_addr gin_trgm_ops)
```

Also, there have been substantial improvements since 9.4.  You will be doing yourself a favor to upgrade to at least 9.6.